# Balls between boxes equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a practice question I don't know how to answer past part (a)

> Consider nonnegative integer solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 26$
>   (a) How many different solutions are there? [3 marks]
>   (b) How many solutions also satisfy: for every $i \in \{1, 2, 3\}, x_i > 0?$ [3 marks]
>   (c) How many solutions also satisfy: for every $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}, x_i$ is even? [3 marks]

For (a) I have ${31}\choose{26}$ and I feel confident in that, but I am unsure of how to answer the next two parts as I can't find anything in my notes that helps me with it.

Thanks

edit: think i have solved the second two parts but could someone tell me if they look right and if my logic is good.

I am considering the 6 unknown integers as boxes and the final answer of 26 as 26 balls.

part(b).
if i consider it as such, could it be that i just need to say that I place one ball in each of the first 3 boxes, leaving me with 23 to be split between all 6 of the boxes so that the answer would be C(28, 23)?

part (c).
I would now glue the balls together so that there are 13 pairs (each considered as one distinct object) to split between the 6 boxes, leaving me with C(18, 13)?

Apologies for the balls in boxes analogy but this is how I was taught this initially and I am trying to relate this to that, so I can have a better grasp of this. Thank you to anyone who has read this :)

Comment: If $x_i>0$ then let $y_i=x_i-1$ and repeat the computation from part $a$.  If all the terms are even you can divide the equation  by $2$.

Comment: Your proposed answers are correct.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The task in part b and part c is to find a way to reduce the problem to part a.

Say for part b, here's a hint. Let:

$$x_i^{'} = x_i - 1, \quad \forall i$$

Now if we find the non-negative solutions to below problem:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{6} x_{i}^{'} = 32$$

we get all positive solutions to the original problem asked.

Which is very similar to part a.

Similarly for part c, replace

$$x_i = 2y_{i} \quad \forall i$$,

where $y_i \in \{0,1,2,..., 13\}$. can you finish now?

Comment: Could you walk me through it please, sorry this is my weakest subject

Comment: I'll update my answer to make it more elaborate for you but I am gonna need some time to do that.

Comment: I really appreciate it I can't stress it enough.

Comment: Wait, if i consider it like balls in boxes, could it be that i just need to say that there I place one in the first 3 boxes, leaving me with 23 to be split between the next so that the answer would be C(28, 23)?

Comment: and then part c would be C(18, 13)?